# What is an efficient way to parse a String in Java?

Tags: java, regex, string, parsing

How should I parse the following `String` using Java to extract the file path?

`?` stands for any number of random charaters

`_` stands for any number of white spaces (no new line)

```
?[LoadFile]_file_=_"foo/bar/baz.xml"?
```

Example:

```
10:52:21.212 [LoadFile] file = "foo/bar/baz.xml"
```

should extract `foo/bar/baz.xml`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
String regex = ".*\\[LoadFile\\]\\s+file\\s+=\\s+\"([^\"].+)\".*";

Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(inputString);
if (!m.find()) 
    System.out.println("No match found.");
else
    String result = m.group(1);
```

The `String` in result should be your file path. (*assuming I didn't make any mistakes*)

You should take a look at the [`Pattern`](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&url=http%3A%2F%2Fjava.sun.com%2Fjavase%2F6%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2Fjava%2Futil%2Fregex%2FPattern.html&ei=HWJwSvTtMIP0NYDQ5dgI&usg=AFQjCNH0h0XmzRaUcuXCvjQPzquOfjdjUQ&sig2=FIjvzu7PrMn9L480P4stRQ) class for some regular expression help.  They can be a very powerful string manipulation tool.

Comment: ".*\\[LoadFile\\]\\s*file\\s*=\\s* \"([^\\\"].*)\".*" would be better to match any number of white spaces

Comment: ".*\"([^\\\"].*)\".*" would be even better as we don't care about the prefix format at all (known by default) and it does not contains any quote.

Comment: FYI, Jean's regex would match no white space as well, ex. [LoadFile]file="foo/bar/baz.xml".  So if you want at least one white space character, use + instead of * as jinguy originally specified.

Comment: @weenaak: I would have read "any number of white spaces" as meaning any number INCLUDING ZERO.

Comment: Two corrections: the method that creates the Matcher object is `.matcher(inputString)` (not capitalized), and you have to *apply* the regex by calling `.matches()` or `.find()` on the Matcher.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: use *subSequence()*.

```
if (line.contains("[LoadFile]"))
  result = line.subSequence(line.indexOf('"'), line.lastIndexOf('"')).toString();
```

On my machine, this consistently takes less than 10,000 ns.

I am taking "efficient" to mean faster.

The *regex* option is considerably slower (about 9 or 10 times slower). The primary advantage of the regex option is that it might be easier for another programmer to figure out what you are doing (but then use comments to help them).

To make the regex option more efficient, pre-compile it:

```
private static final String FILE_REGEX = ".*\\[LoadFile\\]\\s+file\\s+=\\s+\"([^\"].+)\".*";
private static final Pattern FILE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(FILE_REGEX);
```

But this still leaves it slower. I record times between 80,000 and 100,000 ns.

The StringTokenizer option is more efficient than the regex:

```
if (line.contains("[LoadFile]")) {
  StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, "\"");
  tokenizer.nextToken();
  result = tokenizer.nextToken();
}
```

This hovers around 40,000 ns for me, putting it in at 2-3 times faster than the regex.

In this scenario, split() is also an option, which for me (using Java 6_13) is just a little faster than the Tokenizer:

```
if (line.contains("[LoadFile]")) {
  String[] values = line.split("\"");
  result = values[1];
}
```

This averages times of 35,000 ns for me.

Of course, none of this is checking for errors. Each option will get a little slower when you start factoring that in, but I think the *subSequnce()* option will still beat them all. You have to know the exact parameters and expectations to figure out how fault-tolerant each option needs to be.

Answer (score 2):

While regular expressions are nice and all, you can also use class `java.util.StringTokenizer` to do the job. The advantage is a more human-friendly code.

```
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(inputString, "\"");
tokenizer.nextElement();
String path = tokenizer.nextElement();
```

And there you go.

Comment: Another advantage of StringTokenizer is that it will probably be more efficient ... provided that it is capable of doing the job at hand.

Comment: It's just that if there happens to be a number of " characters in the first set of random characters the tokenizer will happily return that as the next element. However, the example suggests the first part of the input line is just a timestamp.

A regex is harder to write, but much more capable of handling wildly different input.

Comment: I agree that a StringTokenizer is not an ideal solution to every parsing problem, but in this case it really seems to me that using a regex is a little like hunting flies with a cannon...

Answer (score 1):

[java.util.regex](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/package-summary.html) is your friend.

Comment: Some people, when confronted with a Stack Overflow question, answer "java.util.regex is your friend" Now the person asking the question has two problems. (Liberally paraphrased from http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2006/03/22/558007.aspx) -- If you're going to suggest using regular expressions, provide an example.

Comment: @Grant Wagner I don't see anything wrong with pointing people in the right direction, even if I don't have time to work out a full solution. If you are not happy with the answer then give a better one instead of wasting your time complaining.

Answer (score 1):

You could make the regular expression a bit shorter than jinguy's. Basically just the RHS without the "'s.

```
    String regex = ".* = \"(.*)\"";
```

Comment: I think jinguy assumed that the path should only be extracted if the line has [LoadFile] in it ...

Comment: When I write a regex, I try to be as specific as possible.